# Large sample distribution of $\beta$

Tags: regression, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a linear model : $y = X \beta + \epsilon$.

Could anyone provide me with some reference or an answer about the unconditional, large sample distribution of the vector of regression coefficients ($\beta$) provided that $X$, the matrix of the predictors, consists of STOCHASTIC predictors ??

Comment: The answer *must* depend on the distribution of $X$.  What are you assuming about that distribution?